# How to Insert data while Copying data in other Table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My problem is, in one button (click event) I need to Copy a data in Table1 (the ToolName) to Table2 (into ToolName) and insert a description to the same row.

Table1
ID - ToolName - Quantity

Table2
ID - ToolName - Description

here`s my codes

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ToolName) SELECT ToolName FROM Table1 WHERE ID = '" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' INSERT INTO Table2 (Description) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox(" succesfully", vbInformation)
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrized queries have two main advantages:

- Security: It is a good way to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities
- Performance: If you regularly invoke the same query just with different parameters a parametrized query might allow the database to cache your queries which is a considerable source of performance gain.
- Extra: You won't have to worry about date and time formatting issues in your database code. Similarly, if your code will ever run on machines with a non-English locale, you will not have problems with decimal points / decimal commas.

Try like this

```
Dim sqlquery As String= "INSERT INTO Table2 (ToolName,Descrption) SELECT ToolName,@Desc FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @Id"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Desc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("succesfully", vbInformation)
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Query syntax like below

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ToolName) 
               SELECT ToolName FROM Table1
               WHERE ID = '" &   DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'; 
               INSERT INTO Table2 (Description) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
```

I think nothing is wrong in query just missing ; between 2 insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Just break it down into two separate updates based on what you already have, use the following code and just pass the ToolName into your update statements

```
    Dim Table_ As String = "getToolName"
    Dim query As String = "SELECT ToolName FROM Table1 WHERE ID = '" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, Table_)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(Table_)
    Dim ToolName As String = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
```